# PDF keep the TrimBox after PDF rotation

Tags: itext

I´ve came across a challenge of creating a trimbox in a PDF with portrait orientation and them rotate it to the landscape orientation, that i did.

```
 pageDict.put(PdfName.ROTATE, new PdfNumber(rot + 270));
```

But my trimbox goes banana. When i define it again with the same coordinates and with the rotation that i defined the trimbox have the same look (perimeter) but the isn´t in the same place.
I´ve tried to define the trimbox calculating the new coordinates but the calculation don´t make much sense, because the calculations (supposed) are ok but the trimbox don´t appear in the place that was defined in the portrait orientation.
Say that i want to define a trimbox in portrait, say that inside is a picture, and when i rotate the page the trimbox continues to involve the same picture, how can this be done?

Anyone have any idea?

cheers

UPDATED:

This is the original TrimBox setted:

[image]

This is the TrimBox after doing the rotation of the PDF page:

[image]

What i want is to set keep the same TrimBox and in the same place independent  if the page is rotated or not.

Cheers

UPDATED:

The rotation of the PDF is in the original POST.
The definition of the TrimBox is made by BIRT with a changed API made by us that defines the boxes, one is TrimBox and is made like this:

```
PdfArray array = (PdfArray) pageDict.get(PdfName.TRIMBOX);
PdfRectangle trimBox = new PdfRectangle(Float.parseFloat(array.getArrayList().get(0).toString()),Float.parseFloat(array.getArrayList().get(1).toString()),Float.parseFloat(array.getArrayList().get(2).toString()), Float.parseFloat(array.getArrayList().get(3).toString()));
pageDict.put(PdfName.TRIMBOX, trimBox);
```

About providing the files, i can´t because Stack don´t let me (need at least 10 reputation).

Cheers

UPDATED:

[Original file](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-qHiKQ6iCkXNTYydDdvZWRsSGM/edit?usp=sharing)

[PDF file after rotation](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-qHiKQ6iCkXbUNhV1B4aVdEUkk/edit?usp=sharing)

Because of the reputation(only 2 links) i remove the image links.

Comment: Actually i don't really understand your issue. After all the trim box is defined as a part of the media box without rotation getting into the way. Maybe you can illustrate what goes wrong? Maybe with some sample file?

Comment: Hi, I understand. If was i, i was struggling to understand what i´m talking about. I´m going to put same print screens, maybe it helps. cheers.

Comment: How do you apply the trim box? And can you supply the PDFfor inspection?

Comment: Hi, update the original post with more info.

Comment: *About providing the files, i can´t because Stack don´t let me (need at least 10 reputation).* -- Stackoverflow does not provide generic file attachment support, merely images are supported from some re onwards. PDFs, therefore, would have to be supplied via a third party file hoster (Dropbox, Google Drive, ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just compared the two files you provided in Adobe Acrobat. And it appears that the PDFs are just as they should be.

[Test_Original.pdf](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-qHiKQ6iCkXNTYydDdvZWRsSGM/edit?usp=sharing):

Entries in page dictionary:

```
/MediaBox [0, 0, 666.29, 912.89]
/TrimBox  [22, 22, 600, 400]
/BleedBox [22, 22, 600, 400]
/ArtBox   [22, 22, 600, 400]
```

In Adobe Acrobat:

[image: Page 1 of Test_Original.pdf displayed in Adobe Acrobat]

[Test_After_ROTATED.pdf](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-qHiKQ6iCkXbUNhV1B4aVdEUkk/edit?usp=sharing):

Entries in page dictionary:

```
/TrimBox  [22, 22, 600, 400]
/MediaBox [0, 0, 666.29, 912.89]
/BleedBox [22, 22, 600, 400]
/ArtBox   [22, 22, 600, 400]
/Rotate   270
```

In Adobe Acrobat:

[image: Page 1 of Test_After_ROTATED.pdf displayed in Adobe Acrobat]

Thus, everything is just fine, only the rotate was added in the page dictionary and, therefore, everything (including the trim box) is rotated.

Thus, I assume the program you use to display the trim box is somewhat limited when rotation is part of the game.

You mentioned BIRT. Maybe BIRT has its own set of information concerning the trim box stored somewhere else (according to the screenshots you used to have in your question with distances from top, left, right, and bottom). In that case those information might also have to be updated when rotating the PDF.

Or, as you use a *changed API made by* you *that defines the boxes,* maybe that API has to be told about rotation effects?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your assistance. I use the Acrobat 7 professional and the pictures that i post is the layout of the trimbox in that software. Do you have any other software that guarantees the visualization that you post? The boxes in the same place besides the different orientation? This can be a bug in the Acrobat 7 professional!!

Comment: I used acrobat version 9.x. Tomorrow in office i can try and double check but the page dictionary entries also indicate that trim box location.

Comment: Yesterday I tested the trim box using Adobe Acrobat 9 Pro version 9.5.5. I just verified the result using Adobe Reader XI version 11.0.3. Thus, either you checked a different PDF than the one you provided or the trim box display in Acrobat 7 was buggy.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your assistance. I get the adobe 9.x and yes the box is there and in the same place, like you said.